# Validation (ASP.Net): Element 'Content' is missing its closing tag

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2008

Morning,

I'm getting the error above when I save my aspx file.

Easy fix I here you say! Simply add `</asp:Content>` to the end of the code.

That gets rid of the error.... then when I press save Visual Studio DELETES the line of code.
I'm guessing there's a problem deeper in the code (some other tag which has not been closed)... but I can't find it!

So there's two questions really!

(1) Why is Visual Studio deleting code I've typed....
(2) Anyone know of a tool I can use to find missing end tags?

Thanks in advance,

Jim

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5626747/Code.txt) is a link to the code

Comment: use Cntrl+K , Ctrl+D to reformat the document, if it is unable to reformat/indent the tags, it will tell you the line with error.

Comment: @Furqan: It reformats fine. Then when I save, the closing tag is deleted.

Comment: @Jim: it may sound foolish, but try restarting VS2008 or your computer(if possible), bcoz sometimes VS2008 behaves in such manner.

Comment: @Furqan: No, I like it - a restart solves many VS problems. Unfortunately, not this time!

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: I couldn't do anything but a cursory examination because I don't have the dependencies, but it looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS.NET may be having difficulties parsing your file. Try this:

Create a new .aspx page that uses the same master page. Try adding your  tag and see if it closes properly. If it does, then we know that VS.NET is still working to some reasonable level.

If that is the case, you can always try adding the markup that breaks to your new page, one step at a time, until you eventually see when the failure occurs.

One idea for a solution may be to simplify your .aspx file. Break down all the stuff that's between your ... tag into separate user controls, a sort of functional decomposition if possible. If it's a VS.NET parsing issue, this may make it easier for VS.NET to understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

This was the offending item:

```
<Style Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="9px" />
```

Thanks for your help guys,

Jim

Answer (score 0):

A tool  to find missing end tags?
You can use functions from http://www.dotnetperls.com/xhtml